# How do i change Drawer item parents Text color?

Tags: android, android-drawer

How do i change the item parents Text color that's in the drawer?
I would like to change the Profiles text Color since i can barely see it in the drawer.

[image]

Comment: "i don't know why stackoverflow is telling me to elaborate" . Its because you have to add code snippet for problem.

Comment: its not that necessary for this question.

Comment: @DickHarris you can change the header's color using styles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a style for you `navigationDrawer` header in you `styles.xml`

```
 <style name="HeaderTextAppreance">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorPrimary</item> 
 </style>
```

and then in your activity access your `navigation header` with it's Id and then try this:

```
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

    Menu menu = navigationView.getMenu();

    MenuItem tools= menu.findItem(R.id.yourId);
    SpannableString s = new SpannableString(tools.getTitle());
    s.setSpan(new TextAppearanceSpan(this, R.style.HeaderTextAppreance), 0, s.length(), 0);
    tools.setTitle(s);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
```

Comment: @DickHarris happy coding :). 
 where is my upvote ? :D